# Google Play In App Review API flow when user is not signed into Google Play

Tags: android, google-api, google-sites

I have been reading the Google Play In App Review API documentation located [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review). But, there is no mention of the case when a user is not signed into Google Play Store. In the case that a user is not signed into GooglePlay, does the api flow prompt the user to sign into GooglePlay then continues with the flow shown on the api documentation site? if the in-app review flow includes the sign in prompt, could you please include a link to where it states this. Thanks!